# how to filter table by underscorejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

i work by underscore function ,i want to filter table by element not exist in author table 
I want to finally display this [[10,20,30,50,60],[80,66],[9,70,4,3] ]

```
var tab=[];
 _.each([[10,20,30,5,50,60],[80,6,66,7,8,2],[9,70,4,3,1]], function (c) {

     var k=   _.filter(c, function (cel) {
         return _.some([1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 7], function (el) {
             return cel != el
         })
     })
     tab.push(k);
});

console.log(tab)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you could use

- [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) for getting an array with filtered arrays,
- [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) for getting only the values who not match the given values and
- [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) for checking the item with the values array.

```js
var array = [[10, 20, 30, 5, 50, 60], [80, 6, 66, 7, 8, 2], [9, 70, 4, 3, 1]],
    values = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 7],
    result = _.map(array, function (a) {
        return _.filter(a, function (v) {
            return !_.contains(values, v);
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.every` instead of `_.some` because the `some` function will return true if ANY of the elements in your filter array do not match the element of your table. So in each case, you are comparing the element of your array to the number 1 (first element of the filter array), and since most of the numbers in your table != 1, the `_.some` function is returning `true` so the number is added to the result of the `_.filter` function.